# Understanding CakePHP: What is the recommended way to modularize an application?

Tags: cakephp, zend-framework, plugins, module, zend-framework2

Usually I work with Zend Framework and now I'm developing an application on CakePHP and trying to understand the framework, in particular how to modularize an application.

In ZF there are modules. Every logical subdivision of an application can (and should) be packed to a separate module. It allows to keep the application structure clear.

There are no modules in CakePHP -- instead the framework provides plugins and I firstly thougth, plugins are the "modules" in CakePHP. But a plugin in CakePHP seems to be something more, than a ZF's module -- "[behaving much like it would if it were an application on its own](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#plugins)". Plugins should apparently be used for bigger things like a blog or a forum, that have characteristics of an independent apllication. So logical units like `User`, `Order`, `Payment`, or `CustomerFeedback`, that only make sense within the application, are probably not suitable as plugins.

Is there a recommended way / What is the recommended way in CakePHP to separate an application into small and well manageable logical parts and so to build a modularized application?

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP plugins and ZF modules have a little bit in common, both can contain MVC logic, library code, configuration, assets, tests, etc., and can pretty much behave like applications on their own.

However there's no need for such "whole application on its own" level of complexity in order for plugins to be the recommended way of managing logic. Of course they can also be used for less complex stuff like splitting your application into logical (and reusable) units.

A payment plugin, a user management plugin, an order processing plugin, a feedback plugin, that all makes sense, and it's neither wrong nor discouraged to use plugins in such a manner.

If you need some inspiration, check out [**Croogo**](https://github.com/croogo/croogo) for example, it's a CakePHP based CMS that manages its different parts using plugins.